# How to handle complex svg as a single path element?

Tags: user-interface, svg, icons, google-material-icons

The code of my svg export using Illustrator looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="37.091" height="48.275" viewBox="0 0 37.091 48.275">
  <g id="group_61" data-name="group 61" transform="translate(-40.455 -22.5)">
    <path id="path_39" data-name="path 39" d="M111.748,27.5a7.894,7.894,0,1,0,7.894,7.894A7.9,7.9,0,0,0,111.748,27.5Zm.816,8.636h-.142v.141h-6.087V34.72h4.672V28.632h1.557Z" transform="translate(-43.653 -3.443)" fill="#cca60d"/>
    <path id="path_40" data-name="path 40" d="M72.166,71.338A4.645,4.645,0,0,1,67.543,76.1H46.919a4.9,4.9,0,0,1-4.906-4.765V38.822a4.9,4.9,0,0,1,4.906-4.765H57.726V32.5H46.919a6.479,6.479,0,0,0-6.464,6.322V71.338a6.479,6.479,0,0,0,6.464,6.322H67.543a6.186,6.186,0,0,0,6.18-6.322V49.913H72.166Z" transform="translate(0 -6.885)" fill="#cca60d"/>
    <path id="path_41" data-name="path 41" d="M108.3,22.5a9.451,9.451,0,1,0,9.452,9.451A9.462,9.462,0,0,0,108.3,22.5Zm0,17.345a7.894,7.894,0,1,1,7.894-7.894A7.9,7.9,0,0,1,108.3,39.845Z" transform="translate(-40.211)" fill="#cca60d"/>
    <path id="path_42" data-name="path 42" d="M116.49,37.224h-4.672v1.557h6.087v-.141h.142v-7.5H116.49Z" transform="translate(-49.137 -5.946)" fill="#cca60d"/>
    <rect id="rec_54" data-name="rec 54" width="10.335" height="1.557" transform="translate(45.693 38.073)" fill="#cca60d"/>
    <rect id="rec_55" data-name="rec 55" width="22.51" height="1.557" transform="translate(45.693 47.133)" fill="#cca60d"/>
    <rect id="rec_56" data-name="rec 56" width="22.51" height="1.557" transform="translate(45.693 57.043)" fill="#cca60d"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How to convert the svg of a single path element, like the following:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="58.547" viewBox="0 0 50 58.547">
  <path id="union_1" data-name="union 1" d="M-1658.173,58.547A3.811,3.811,0,0,1-1662,54.762V8.789c0-2.3,1.433-3.973,3.406-3.973h21.441a1.67,1.67,0,0,1,1.668,1.667,1.67,1.67,0,0,1-1.668,1.668h-21.393a1.54,1.54,0,0,0-.118.639V54.762a.462.462,0,0,0,.492.45h36.636a1.284,1.284,0,0,0,.375-.042V25.882a1.67,1.67,0,0,1,1.668-1.668,1.67,1.67,0,0,1,1.668,1.668v29.26a3.377,3.377,0,0,1-3.71,3.4Zm5.66-10.426a1.669,1.669,0,0,1-1.668-1.668,1.669,1.669,0,0,1,1.668-1.668h25.2a1.67,1.67,0,0,1,1.668,1.668,1.67,1.67,0,0,1-1.668,1.668Zm0-9.558a1.669,1.669,0,0,1-1.668-1.668,1.669,1.669,0,0,1,1.668-1.668h25.2a1.67,1.67,0,0,1,1.668,1.668,1.67,1.67,0,0,1-1.668,1.668Zm0-10.427a1.669,1.669,0,0,1-1.668-1.668,1.669,1.669,0,0,1,1.668-1.668h25.2a1.67,1.67,0,0,1,1.668,1.668,1.67,1.67,0,0,1-1.668,1.668Zm28.929-5.1a11.464,11.464,0,0,1-11.449-11.379A11.53,11.53,0,0,1-1623.653,0l.14,0a11.434,11.434,0,0,1,8.043,3.278,11.447,11.447,0,0,1,3.469,8.1,11.528,11.528,0,0,1-11.379,11.651ZM-1629.9,5.522a8.7,8.7,0,0,0-2.495,6.23,8.781,8.781,0,0,0,8.768,8.663,8.792,8.792,0,0,0,8.878-8.768,8.779,8.779,0,0,0-8.768-8.769h-.217A8.713,8.713,0,0,0-1629.9,5.522Zm-22.608,13.055a1.669,1.669,0,0,1-1.668-1.667,1.669,1.669,0,0,1,1.668-1.668h13.034a1.669,1.669,0,0,1,1.667,1.668,1.669,1.669,0,0,1-1.668,1.667Zm28.852-4.7a1.18,1.18,0,0,1-1.177-1.163V6.152a1.321,1.321,0,0,1,1.32-1.279,1.32,1.32,0,0,1,1.319,1.279v5.1h3.317a1.309,1.309,0,0,1,1.309,1.309,1.309,1.309,0,0,1-1.309,1.309Z" transform="translate(1662 0)" fill="#e31919"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: First you will have to transform the rects to paths. Next, since every path you have is translated a different amount you will need to transform the d attribute to all relative coords (lowercase commands) and modify the first move to command (M) accordingly. After eliminating all the transforms you'll be able to concatenate all the d attributes for a unic path.

Comment: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ is a good visual, single path editor

Answer (score 1):

This is a multi-step process and if you have any basic shapes other than paths it requires a vector editor like Illustrator/Affinity Designer/Inkscape (there are some JS libraries to do it as well).

### Step 1: Convert shapes to paths

Copy the SVG and paste it into your favorite vector editor or save the SVG as a file and open it in your editor. Use the pen tool (pretty universal among all vector editors) and anywhere on a path (line) of the shape add a new anchor. With a single new anchor on any shape it will force it to be a path when you save.

### Step 2: Save the SVG

I use Illustrator so I export as an SVG but it's pretty similar in any program.

### Optional Step - Drop it into [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

You can do this and it will combine some paths for you if the settings are right, it can also reduce the overall size. Then you can copy and paste the text into a text editor skipping the next step.

### Step 3: Open the SVG in a text editor

VS Code or Sublime, even notepad technically works fine.

### Step 4: Combine the paths that have identical attributes.

Just take the path out of one and paste it after the end of the path in another as long as the stroke-width, stroke, fill, etc all match. In this example they all match so it's ready to merge.

For example if you have:

```html
<path d="M1 1 L2 2 H0 1Z" />
<path d="M5 5 L 7 7 H0 8Z" />
```

after combining you would have:

```html
<path d="M1 1 L2 2 H0 1Z M5 5 L 7 7 H0 8Z" />
```

I usually leave a space after the last path and before the next to help me remember that I merged the paths at one point. Always make sure to keep a copy of the original file in case you mess up.

Your shared example would look like this:

```html
<svg fill="#cca72c" viewBox="0 0 38 50">
    <path d="M32.17,42.82a4.65,4.65,0,0,1-4.53,4.76H6.92A4.91,4.91,0,0,1,2,42.81V10.3A4.91,4.91,0,0,1,6.92,5.53H17.73V4H6.92A6.47,6.47,0,0,0,.46,10.3V42.82a6.47,6.47,0,0,0,6.46,6.32H27.54A6.19,6.19,0,0,0,33.73,43a.53.53,0,0,0,0-.13V21.39H32.17Z M27.35,9.64H22.68V11.2h6.09v-.14h.14V3.56H27.35Z M5.7 16.44L11.52 16.44 16.03 16.44 16.03 17.99 5.7 17.99 5.7 16.44z M5.7 25.5L13.89 25.5 28.2 25.5 28.2 27.05 5.7 27.05 5.7 25.5z M5.7 35.41L13.44 35.41 28.2 35.41 28.2 36.96 5.7 36.96 5.7 35.41z M28.09.86a9.45,9.45,0,0,0-9.45,9.45c.5,12.54,18.41,12.54,18.9,0A9.46,9.46,0,0,0,28.09.86Zm0,17.35A7.9,7.9,0,1,1,29.68,2.58C38.86,4.63,37.6,18,28.1,18.21Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I followed your steps, but the svg does not display correctly

Comment: Odds are you're talking about your circle which when I imported it into Illustrator was a solid circle and needed to have the smaller circle subtracted from the larger circle in order to show the clock hands. In general when working between SVG as text and SVG in an editor there will be changes needed to make sure the image is correct in the editor before you export as all paths and merge them as described.

Comment: I'm not sure how are you guys, but I draw a simple vector figure consisting of 4 polygons in InkScape and SVGOMG doesn't do jack shit with it. I want to unify the paths and remove transformations and all crap.

Comment: @CsabaToth Without seeing your exact output it's difficult to guess what your issue is but if you need to remove transforms there's an extension for doing so in Inkscape https://github.com/Klowner/inkscape-applytransforms you would need to do this before exporting the file since SVGOMG does not flatten transforms. Aside from that you made need to adjust the global settings in SVGOMG or just use SVGO which gives more granular control.

Comment: @JHeth Thx, note that I didn't downvote or anything. What ended up helping is grouping the triangles into one object. That resulted in a single path.